# How to find lowest left and down value in coordinates of dataframe with pandas python?

Tags: python, pandas

The values are coordinates so i want the point that is the lowest left and top coordinate, in this case is (709.4787,265.1082)

```
x           y
709.4787    265.1082
699.0114    303.2652    
842.2347    343.4130
```

How can i do that?

Comment: you can simply user iterrows() and set conditions for each col x and y. Store the index if condition is found.

Comment: what if min and max are not in the same row?7

Comment: @Valentino usually they are not in the same in my case.

Comment: do you want to know the ROW where x is max and y is max (could be two different rows) or do you want to know the max of x and y

Comment: The max of `y` is not 0.2779 in your sample.

Comment: @Valentino yes that's true. I just want the most left and lowest top coordinate. How can i get it?

Comment: Your request is a little ambiguous. Is a matter of distance from origin? Do you want the farthest point from (0, 0) in your sample?

Comment: @Valentino in deep is the closest.

Comment: but the closest would be 0.0914, 0.2738. And why then min and max? The closest shouldn't be min and min? Maybe could you explain your real problem, so we can understand better what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the row (the *same* row) where `x` is mininum *and* `y` is maximum you can do:

```
df.loc[(df['x'] == df['x'].min()) & (df['y'] == df['y'].max())]
```

Using your data sample, this will return the third row, which satisfies both conditions:

```
   x  y
2  1  2
```

If you just want the minimum of a column and the maximum of the other column, use [pandas DataFrame agg](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html):

```
df.agg({'x':'min', 'y':'max'})
```

which returns, using your data sample:

```
x    1
y    2
dtype: int64
```

#### EDIT after question edit

So it is just a matter of distance from origin. First you can create a new column where you calculate the distance from origin, and then select the row with the minimum distance.

```
df['d'] = np.sqrt(df['x']**2 + df['y']**2)
df.loc[df['d'] == df['d'].min()]
```

This works assuming that all your coordinates (x and y) are positive. If you have negative values, translate the axis by an offset so that all numbers are positive before calculating distances.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please help me with the new update?

Answer (score 0):

```
df[(df.x == df.x.min()) & (df.y == df.y.max())]
```